How do I convert my softbox to Bowens mount?
I've had a softbox with a mount like this for a while, as I was using it with a speedlight:

Here is the back of my actual item (there seem to be a few less screws on mine):

but I recently got one that has a mount like this (I believe this is called a "Bowens mount"):

and I like that I can mount many different types of lights.
I was hoping that I could just remove the mount and replace it, but though it spins around I can't figure out how to actually remove it. Is there anyway to convert the first one to be like the second one?

Do not break it. It has been useful to you for a specific usage. Keep it as it is. Softboxes are reasonably cheap, so get another if you need it. It is a common practice to have "redundant" gear just in case.

In the first and last images you can see three silver screws with washers; those secure the speed ring to the umbrella frame and allow the speed ring to rotate. The fist speedring is an S-type (speedlight), and the last is a bowens type. Between those two it is likely that the speedrings can be interchanged.
The construction of yours looks to be different and I doubt it can be swapped to a different speedring. However, you can get an S-type bracket that accepts bowens mount modifiers rather cheaply. That would allow you to mount your bowens type umbrella to your speedlights.

Dang, ok, thanks. To your last point, yes I have an S-type bracket that I can install Bowens modifiers on. What I want is the reverse - to use this softbox with a light that isn't a speedlight.

It depends on the exact make and construction of the softbox. Some softboxes have exchangeable so-called speed rings or speed ring adapters, that can be detached and exchanged for another mount.
Typically that is true for soft boxes made for studio strobes (so the exact opposite use-case you need). Whether your exact soft box can be modified depends on the manufacturer. The item in your image looks like the adapter could be detached, but it does not look like any standard speed ring mount, that I know of.
Your best bet would be to contact the manufacturer. If they can provide a conversion kit, you also might be able to find that on their website.
